# C# command-line argument with newline fails in C# but not in python. Need to make the c# work

Tags: c#, python

Env: .NET 3.5 Visual Studio 2008 SP1, on Win XP SP3, Python 2.7. Corporate image, no admin rights.

In C# 3.5, I want to pass a parameter to a command-line program, and this parameter contains newlines. It works in Python 2.7 but not in C#.

When body contains newline, c# truncates the result, but python passes it correctly.

Python code

```
cmd = self.app_path + ' email -Subject "' + subject + '" -From "' + address_from + '" -To "' + address_to +'" -Body "' + body +'"'
cmd_result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

C# code:

```
string Command = "<path to executable>";                 
string arguments = "  email -From " + FromAddress + " -To " + ToAddress + " -Subject \"" + SubjectLine + "\" -Body \"" + emailBody + "\" ";
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Command, arguments);
start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
start.CreateNoWindow = false;
start.UseShellExecute = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(start);
```

Any idea?

Update: body in the python example and emailBody in the c# example contain the same string, as strings are represented in each language.

Update: noticed the command wasn't terminated correctly in the python code. I added + '"' at the end of line 2. The code ran as before.

Also, as you can tell, the app called sends the body (emailBody) parameter content as an email body.

Comment: Ed, I mean that python passes the newline characters in a manner that is understood correctly by the application, as in, they are newline characters, not string terminations.

Comment: Do the C# and the python code call the same process with the same arguments?

Comment: Just out of interest, is it possible to send the email body to "standard input" for the process? If so, that could be a good workaround... See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Comment: I'm thinking...Maybe it is an encoding issue? Thus the newlines may not be recognized correctly

Comment: @GianT971, yeah, I'm leaning there too. I'm very confused though.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I think it is the process you call that does not take the arguments correctly; it is not the C# that is involved, and as a proof of that:

- Create a new windows form application
- Make sure that the Main signature looks like this:

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  ```
- Make sure that the call of your Main Form (named Form1) looks like this:

  ```
      if (args==null)
      {
          Application.Run(new Form1()); 
      }
      else
      {
          Application.Run(new Form1(args)); 
      }
  ```
- Add a textbox to your form, with the multiline property set to true
- Add a button to your form
- Run the application once
- Then Put this in the code of your button1_Click function (replace TheNameOfTheCurrentApp):

  ```
      string Command = "TheNameOfTheCurrentApp";                 
      string arguments = textBox1.Text;
      System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Command, arguments);
      start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
      start.CreateNoWindow = true;
      start.UseShellExecute = true;
      System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(start);
  ```
- Add this constructor to your form:

  ```
  public Form1(string[] args)
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      textBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", args);
  }
  ```
- Then run your app, insert muliple lines in your textbox and click the button. The same app will appear with the textbox correctly filled with the line breaks

Comment: The application I call is not developed by us, but by another team, and we cannot modify it.

Comment: And the question then becomes, why does it work when calling the app from python 2.7? Does it perhaps have to do with byte strings versus unicode16?

Comment: Honestly I don't see any other cause than the encoding, if it works for python and not for C#. You ought to try to find a way for your C# code to send the information in a different encoding style

Comment: Will do. Will report on results.